# Configure Azure Traffic Manager over 2 web apps with custom domain and SSL

Tags: azure, ssl, dns, azure-traffic-manager, custom-domain

### Background

I have two websites:
- web1.azurewebsites.net
- web2.azurewebsites.net

I have added a traffic manager called webtm.trafficmanager.net.

web1.azurewebsites.net is configured with a custom domain web.example.com. I've also added a wildcard SSL certificate to it (i.e., *.example.com). If I request web.example.com it serves the website without any issues.

### Requirement

I need to setup Traffic Manager on top of these two sites. So, if web1.azurewebsites.net is down/offline, then Traffic Manager can switch to web2.azurewebsites.net automatically.

### Implementation question

I've read these SO answers ([SO 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50803998/11480716), [SO 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40399500/11480716)) and [this docs article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-domain-traffic-manager), however, I have some doubts. I would really appreciate if someone can confirm my understanding outlined below, please?

**Step 1:** I understand that I'll have to update DNS records to something like: `web.example.com. 60 IN CNAME webtm.trafficmanager.net.`. Remove other DNS/CNAME records that point `web.example.com to web1.azurewebsites.net`.

**Step 2:** I'll need to remove the current custom domain mapping from web1.azurewebsites.net and then re-add it. Set custom domain to web.example.com and the CNAME configuration will show the traffic manager endpoint. No DNS changes required in this step?

**Step 3:** Add a custom domain to web2.azurewebsites.net set the custom domain to web.example.com and the CNAME configuration will show the traffic manager endpoint. No DNS changes required in this step?

**Step 4:** No changes to the SSL certificate added to web1.azurewebsites.net.

**Step 5:** Add the SSL certificate to web2.azurewebsites.net.

Now, accessing https://web.example.com should hit the traffic manager. It will see that web1.azurewebsites.net is online, so it will direct users to that. If web1.azurewebsites.net goes down, it will auto redirect users to web2.azurewebsites.net.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your steps are mostly correct. What you want to do is to follow this document---[Configure a custom domain name in Azure App Service with Traffic Manager integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-domain-traffic-manager)

In step 3 and step 4, the traffic manager domain name will show under **CNAME configuration**. **Select** it and click **Add custom domain**. No other steps are required.

> If a record is already in use and you need to preemptively bind your
>   apps to it, you can create an additional CNAME record. For example, to
>   preemptively bind `www.contoso.com` to your app, create a CNAME record
>   from `awverify.www` to `contoso.trafficmanager.net`. You can then add
>   `www.contoso.com` to your app without the need to change the `www`
>   CNAME record. For more information, see [Migrate an active DNS name to
>   Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-custom-dns-migrate-domain).

You also could see the full steps in [this blog](https://jpda.dev/azure-traffic-manager-with-web-apps-in-different-subscriptions-75877d22a34b). In this blog, it uses a second web app in a different subscription, so it selects an external endpoint for that. If your first web app and your Traffic Manager instance are in the same subscription, use an Azure Endpoint, as you would normally, and choose the web app in that subscription.

Let me know if you face any questions.

Comment: The awverify.www records is only for root domains, right? Not for sub domains?

Comment: Both root and sub domains support. You can look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-custom-dns-migrate-domain#create-domain-verification-record). It also depends on your domain provider that support or not to add the `awverify`.